# Tabnine Chat in Visual Studio 2022 is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2022, tabnine

I've installed the `Tabnine` extension in `Visual Studio 2022` (Version 17.7.6) via the Extensions menu. After installation, I restarted `Visual Studio` and logged in to `Tabnine`. However, I've noticed that the 'Start Tabnine Chat' and 'Snooze' features are disabled, despite restarting `Visual Studio` multiple times.

I've checked that the `Tabnine` extension appears under the extensions list, but these features remain inactive. Could someone please advise on how to troubleshoot this issue? Should I be taking any additional steps to enable these features?

[image]

Comment: https://www.tabnine.com/pricing seems to indicate that chat is available to Pro/Enterprise users.  Are you _paying_ for anything basically or no?  There are free trials it seems as well

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Tabnine chat to work, one need to be logged in.
Click "Open Hub" and register/login